# jquery form advance form cloning

Tags: jquery, forms, clone

How to make a form where it can be added rows on clicking the ADD ROW link and can be deleted while click remove. Also i have a dropdown list in my form which has following options 
1. ---Select--- by default
2. Asset 
3. No Asset

Now when a user selects Asset a dynamic form show appear right below the current row.
The dynamic box should have this fields 
1. Asset Type: One dropdown list (whose values should be populated with ajax)
2. Name: A simple input text field
3. Serial No: Text field
4. Description: Text field

This form should have option to added and remove and even for those added rows dynamic form box should be generated.

```
 <table id="expense_table" class="">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th>Sl. No</th>
                <th>Particulars</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
                <th>Rate</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
           </thead>
    <tbody>
            <tr id="row_1">
                <td>1</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="particulars" /></td>
                <td>
                    <select id="expense_type" name="expense_type" class="exp_type span2">
                        <option value="">---Select---</option>
                        <option value="asset">Asset</option><!---when Asset is selected a dynamic box with some fields should appear---->
                        <option value="non_asset">Non Asset</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="qty" class="input-small" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="rate" class="input-small"  /></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="amount" class="input-small"  /></td>
                <td>X</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="asset_details_1"><td colspan="7"> <!----- here should be the dynamic box with the fields---->
</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have worked with form cloning and i got it working in when i dont have the dropdown list but with dropdownlist and dynamic box i m unable to do so how can i receive the data in server in php. Help me please. I dont want the whole code to be written for me but ur guidance in right direction is wt i want. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well jQuery.addRow plugin will help you do clone select box.

take a look at [here](http://www.examplet.buss.hk/jquery/table.addrow.php)

its allows to add and delete row dynamically.

```
$(".addRow").btnAddRow();
$(".delRow").btnDelRow();
```

above two also have callback function.

You have `expense_type` id for select box and its cloning too and there must not be same id for more than one dom.

now your dynamically added select box do not have events assigned to it so use `.on`

```
$('select[name="name="expense_type""]').on('change',function(){
   //write code
});
```

Comment: Adding and removing i m able to do with my code but the problem is i have one dropdown list and if a user selects a particular option that is "Asset" a box/div should automatically appear right after that row having some one dropdownlist and 3 textbox. And this should be work able with all the cloned rows aswell.

Comment: hey bro i tried this but still some problem, can u help a little http://jsfiddle.net/kkAM6/

Comment: @Chakra sorry for late reply now tell me what help you need...i have seen ur fiddle...and i guess you need to append new html when drop down change at specific area right.?

Comment: yes bro when the user select the option ASSET in ddl a small form should be appended right below the current row. This works for the all the rows but when append the box for the last row and then try adding new rows the script doesnt work.